# Testing Laravel Http Client Pool with retries

Tags: laravel, tdd

I try to mock a pooled request with error handling. I would expect to hit the `retry` once, however I recognised this works only for non-pooled request.

My method:

```php
protected function queryRecords($zones): array
{
    return Http::pool(function (Pool $pool) use ($zones) {
        foreach ($zones as $zone) {
            $responses[] = $pool->as($zone)
                ->withToken(decrypt($this->token($this->spoke)))
                ->retry(20, 200, function ($exception, $request): bool {
                    $request->withToken(decrypt($this->token($this->spoke)));
                    return true;
                }, throw: false)
                ->get('https://my.api.com/foo/' . $zone . '/ALL?api-version=2018-09-01');
        }
        return $responses ?? [];
    });
}
```

For testing Http client, I use the Http::faker facade:

```php
/** @test */
public function run_dns_syn_on_hub_and_spoke_tenants()
    Http::fake([
      'https://my.api.com/foo/*' => Http::sequence()
      ->push('stub_1.json')
      ->push(status: 401)
      ->push('stub_2.json')
    ]);

   $zones = ['zone1', 'zone2', 'zone3'];

   $responses = $this->queryRecords($zones);

   // make some assertions
}
```

Does anyone hit know a solution for this?

Comment: I also ran across this problem, and after looking at the PendingRequest class, `send()` method you can see the issue. This Laracast article https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/should-retry-be-ignored-when-sending-asyncpool-requests explains it. Unfortunately havent found an answer though.